# Обновление UI во время выполнения

Tags: java, android

Что нужно дописать в код, чтобы текст обновлялся на кнопке раз в секунду, или ткните где искать инфу, заранее благодарю.

> [image: code]

Answer (score 1):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            // добавить текст на кнопку
       }
}, 1000);
```